# Post method returns null in Angular 13

Tags: angular, http, post

This is my service document :

```js
login(username: any, password: any): Observable<UserInfo> {
    const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('username', username)
        .set('password', password);

    console.log(username, password);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/login`, body);
}
```

and this is my component file :

```js
handleLogin() {
    this.loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe((res)=> {
        console.log(res, "--------------response---------------");
        this.router.navigate(['/home']); 
    });
}
```

When I try to console my response in order to see what i posted in order to  make some login based on that, it returns null

I dont know what to do.PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Check your network tab and see what the actual API response is. It could well be an error which you don't seem to be handling.

Comment: maybe this is by design or you have a problem on the server. Looks like the server returns `null`